# How can I count phrases and use the phrases as headers in Python?

Tags: python, text, count

I have a file in which I am trying to obtain counts of phrases.  There are about 100 phrases I need to count in certain lines of text.  As a simple example, I have the following:

```
phrases = """hello
name
john doe
"""

text1 = 'id=1: hello my name is john doe.  hello hello.  how are you?'
text2 = 'id=2: I am good.  My name is Jane.  Nice to meet you John Doe'

header = ''
for phrase in phrases.splitlines():
    header = header+'|'+phrase
header = 'id'+header
```

I'd like to be able to have output which looks like this:

```
id|hello|name|john doe
1|3|1|1
2|0|1|1
```

I have the header down.  I'm just not sure how to count each phrase and append the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a list of the headers

```
In [6]: p=phrases.strip().split('\n')

In [7]: p
Out[7]: ['hello', 'name', 'john doe']
```

use a regex using [word-boundaries](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) i.e. `\b` to get the number of occurances avoiding partial matches. the flag `re.I` is to make the search case-insensitive.

```
In [11]: import re

In [14]: re.findall(r'\b%s\b' % p[0], text1)
Out[14]: ['hello', 'hello', 'hello']

In [15]: re.findall(r'\b%s\b' % p[0], text1, re.I)
Out[15]: ['hello', 'hello', 'hello']

In [16]: re.findall(r'\b%s\b' % p[1], text1, re.I)
Out[16]: ['name']

In [17]: re.findall(r'\b%s\b' % p[2], text1, re.I)
Out[17]: ['john doe']
```

put a `len()` around that to get the number of pattern found.

Answer (score 2):

You can count words in a string using `.count()`

```
>>> text1.lower().count('hello')
3
```

so this should work (aside from the mismatches mentioned in the comments below)

```
phrases = """hello
name
john doe
"""

text1 = 'id=1: hello my name is john doe.  hello hello.  how are you?'
text2 = 'id=2: I am good.  My name is Jane.  Nice to meet you John Doe'

texts = [text1,text2]

header = ''
for phrase in phrases.splitlines():
    header = header+'|'+phrase
header = 'id'+header
print header

for id,text in enumerate(texts):
    textcount = [id]
    for phrase in header.split('|')[1:]:
        textcount.append(text.lower().count(phrase))
    print "|".join(map(str,textcount))
```

The above assumes you have a list of the texts in order of their `id`'s, but if they all begin with `'id=n'` you could do something like:

```
for text in texts:
    id = text[3]  # assumes id is 4th char
    textcount = [id]
```

Comment: that's great.  I knew it  had to be something simple.  I was trying to split the text by spaces and it was a mess.  Thank you!

Comment: Using `.count()` by itself can be dangerous in this context because of unintended matches.  Consider "Othello", for example, or "enamel".

Comment: @DSM Yeah I guess the solution there would be to use regex, but I can't help with that.

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't answer your question (@askewchan and @Fredrik have done that), I thought I'd offer some advice about the rest of your approach:

You might be better served by defining your phrases in a list:

```
phrases = ['hello', 'name', 'john doe']
```

which then lets you skip the loop in creating the header:

```
header = 'id|' + '|'.join (phrases)
```

and you can leave out the `.split ('|')[1:]`  part in askewchan's answer, for example, in favour of just `for phrase in phrases:`

Comment: @myname no worries, hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

```
phrases = """hello
name
john doe
"""

text1 = 'id=1: hello my name is john doe.  hello hello.  how are you?'
text2 = 'id=2: I am good.  My name is Jane.  Nice to meet you John Doe'

import re
import collections

txts = [text1, text2]
phrase_list = phrases.split()
print "id|%s" % "|".join([ p for p in phrase_list])
for txt in txts:
    (tid, rest) = re.match("id=(\d):\s*(.*)", txt).groups()

    counter = collections.Counter(re.findall("\w+", rest))
    print "%s|%s" % ( tid, "|".join([str(counter.get(p, 0)) for p in phrase_list]))
```

Gives:

```
id|hello|name|john|doe
1|3|1|1|1
2|0|1|0|0
```